# .png file not accepting CSS edits

Tags: html, css, png

When I link a .png file to my webpage from a local media folder, it appears on the page but nothing I do in CSS affects the image. If I adjust the height in html within the  tag it will affect the picture, but nothing I do in CSS will. I've already checked to see and everything in CSS is affecting the rest of the webpage. Just not the .png image.

image is as such:

```
`<img src = "media/LenusLogo.png" alt = "company logo" class = 
"logo"/>`
```

and CSS is:

```
img.logo {
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please remove space character before and after the `=`

Comment: It appears to be working fine, even with space characters before and after '='. Why do you have ` before and after the img tag? Maybe that's the problem

Comment: @Rubenxfd ` character in StackOverflow is used to wrap code. I think OP used ` and try to embed code block. However, the code block also have indentation of 4 spaces, thus makes ` displayed in question.

Comment: What isn't working about it? Note: `margin: auto` and a dynamic width, will not work. Is that the problem? Please state what about it isn't working.

Comment: I realized that space before or after `=` is totally fine. The specification is: https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/syntax.html#elements-attributes

Comment: I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/fyebv7vu/) that seems to work as you intend. Are you sure it's not a caching problem, i.e. the browser is using an old version of the css file?